# What happen to ejb schedulers when computer time changes?

Tags: java, ejb, scheduler

I am quite new to java ejb programming. Recently I have come up with the problem where my ejb scheduler suddenly stop running when i change my computer time. Is this the expected behaviour of the scheduler? If it is are there any methods that I can use to run scheduler even with computer time changes?

I have created my scheduler using annotations. I am using jboss server to run my application. This is how i created my timer.

```
@Schedule(second = "*/5", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
    public void mySchedule() {
        Timestamp t = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println("Time:"+t);
    }
```

Comment: Could you provided more details? How did you create the scheduler? With annotations? With the API? Was it persistent or not? What values did you use?

Comment: Sorry, I have added the details. it was non-persistent timer and I tried with a persistent timer also. But problem still happened

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: what kind of time change did you do?

Comment: I backdated my time and see whether scheduler works fine. But It didn't

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. Try this: change method signature to: `public void mySchedule(Timer timer)`, and  add at the end, `System.out.println("Next timeout:"+ timer.getNextTimeout());`. Until next timeout is reached it would execute.

Comment: It will give the next timeout timestamp and also stops after scheduler stops.Is there any way to reinvoke the scheduler by user input after i backdate my pc time (Once scheduler stops).

Comment: It doesn't stop. It waits till the next timeout. As you backdated the time, it doesn't reach the next timeout.

Comment: @areus But if it is the case, It should triggered when I reset my time to previous time. As a example lets say scheduler stops at 10:30:05 and its nextTimeout is 10:30:10. If I reset to my scheduler to 10:30:00 after backdated, timer should triggered? Is it correct?

Comment: I think it should. But that kind of behaviour is not covered by the EJB spec

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work as expected. Also If I change the time to a future date scheduler syncs with computer time after some time with continuous timeouts. Do you know how ejb scheduler operates? Is it refer to a system clock or ejb container invoke some other method to perform timeout?